# Best way to add a custom polygon to a folium map in any location?

Tags: python, polygon, geojson, folium

I am new to Folium but managing fine with the basics. I have one slightly abstract question however as to the best way to do something:

I have my own polygon marker shapes (example below in geojson is a cocktail glass with the letter J for Jameson on it!), and I want to be able to call this shape and plot it into a folium map at any location (very important) and scale (less important, as I could have different files for different scales as a workaround).

At the moment I have it as a geojson but obviously geojson specifies an actual location on earth (and therefore size).

So what I want is an abstract shape in a stored format that I can tell folium to "place" on the map where I want it (which could be anywhere on earth!), and ideally any size (but location most important).

Therefore, what's the easiest and simplest way to do this? Some other format of shape data I am guessing?

My example shape in geojson:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "cocktail",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Layer": "0", "SubClasses": null, "ExtendedEntity": null, "Linetype": null, "EntityHandle": null, "Text": null }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 3.095, 7.56494, 0.0 ], [ 3.63938, 6.88867, 0.0 ], [ 3.63656, 6.30507, 0.0 ], [ 3.30826, 6.1844, 0.0 ], [ 4.11638, 6.176, 0.0 ], [ 3.79368, 6.30507, 0.0 ], [ 3.78244, 6.88867, 0.0 ], [ 4.33524, 7.56494, 0.0 ], [ 3.095, 7.56494, 0.0 ] ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "Layer": "0", "SubClasses": null, "ExtendedEntity": null, "Linetype": null, "EntityHandle": null, "Text": null }, "geometry": { "type": "LineString", "coordinates": [ [ 3.61692, 7.16086, 0.0 ], [ 3.76004, 7.15804, 0.0 ], [ 3.76563, 7.37696, 0.0 ], [ 3.89469, 7.37696, 0.0 ], [ 3.89469, 7.41342, 0.0 ], [ 3.6225, 7.4106, 0.0 ], [ 3.62532, 7.37131, 0.0 ], [ 3.72071, 7.36849, 0.0 ], [ 3.71511, 7.20296, 0.0 ], [ 3.60851, 7.20578, 0.0 ], [ 3.61692, 7.16086, 0.0 ] ] } }
]
}
```

Comment: you may want to export folium map into image format and then overlay your logo using PIL or OPENCV.

Comment: That's an idea but I really need this to be done before plotting happens so it needs to be some sort of shape data.

Comment: How about a custom icon using `folium.features.CustomIcon` ?

Comment: Good suggestion, this worked!

Comment: glad, it worked. Pls, upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to a suggestion through [Ruslan S.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10396469/ruslan-s) I tried using the `folium.features.CustomIcon` function and this worked:

```
icon_url = "https://yourwebsitelinkorlocationoficon.com/cocktail.png"

icon = folium.features.CustomIcon(icon_url,icon_size=(40, 40))

folium.Marker([p1_lat, p1_lon], icon=icon).add_to(testmap)
```